# UICollectionViewCell flip animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to have a flip animation with my cells when the user touches them. When the cell is flipped, the backside should show another image.

I have solved it by putting a coverimage above my cell content that will be hidden or not.

How can I force a cell to do the flip animation? I could only make it working with a reload of the cell, but this has sideeffects.

How can I force a flip animation and change the state of the cell when it is turned by 180 degrees?

Here is the code inside my UICollectionViewCell that contains the animation:

```
func makeImageVisible(visible:Bool, animated: Bool){

        if(animated){
            UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.coverImageView.hidden = visible
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            self.coverImageView.hidden = visible
        }
    }
```

The cell contains some views that are covered by the coverimage. Depending on the state the coverimage is hidden or not.

And here is my cellForIndexPath-method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MemoryGameCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MemoryGameCell

    cell.setImage(self.image!)
    cell.makeImageVisibile(self.imageIsVisible(indexPath), animated: self.imageIsTemporaryVisible(indexPath))

    return cell
}
```

If a cell gets touched I put it in the visiblecells-array and reload the collectionview. I tried it without reloading the collectionview by calling makeImageVisible directly, but then nothing happens.
Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Just have a subView in the UITableViewCell. On didSelectRow provide an animation on the subView using 
+ transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:. As an option, pass in TransitionFlipFromBottom and swap out your old view with the new view in the animation block.

Comment: You can also do a custom UIAnimation using a CATransform layer. Just rotate the view's layer half way (to where the view's y axis is facing the screen so the view is invisible) and then swap out the view with the new view and rotate appropriately.

Comment: I edited my post and added the code I have so far. Sorry, I wrote TrableViewCell at first but was meaning CollectionviewCell.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a UIView animation on didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method of the UITableView. Here is the method you should be calling :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      if(animated){
            UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.coverImageView.hidden = visible
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            self.coverImageView.hidden = visible
        } }
```

Comment: I tried this, but then nothing happens. The view doesn't get animated. The only way to start the animation is to reload the cell and start the animation from there. But then I have the error with the image from the last animated cell that shows up for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Here an full explanation :
Your collectionViewCell have two views (like front & back) that you can hidden for the flip effect. First you mark back hidden, then you can flip on didselect. And if you want to reflip on scroll, implement scrollViewDidScroll delegate from the collectionView. Please make sure you inverse the animation transition and you are acting on the contentView of the cell.

Here the code on you cell :

```
func flip() {
        let flipSide: UIView.AnimationOptions = versoView.isHidden ? .transitionFlipFromLeft : .transitionFlipFromRight
        UIView.transition(with: self.contentView, duration: 0.3, options: flipSide, animations: { [weak self]  () -> Void in
            self?.frontView.isHidden = !(self?.frontView.isHidden ?? true)
            self?.backView.isHidden = !(self?.backView.isHidden ?? false)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Here is the code for you collectionView :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyFlippingCell else {
            return
        }
        // if you have the current cell then flip
        cell.flip()
        // you can save it for reflip on didscroll
}
```